# Amazon RDS - How to get MySQL slow query logs in native format, and not CSV?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, mysql-slow-query-log

A colleague sent me some **slow query logs in CSV format** from an Amazon RDS instance running MySQL.

Is there a way to convert them into **native MySQL slow query log format**? Or, even better, obtain directly slow query logs in MySQL native format from the web console of a RDS instance?

Comment: Are you hoping to use pt-query-digest?  Or myslowdump?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I wanted to use pt-query-digest, and some other Percona tool.